# QString methods causing undefined reference to errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <Method.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QVector< QString> vec;

    QVector< QVector < QString> > mat;

    vector<string> vect;

    vector<vector<string> > matr;




    vec = Method::bogus(vect);

    mat = Method::bogusMa(matr);

}

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <Method.h>

using namespace::std;

QVector<QString> bogus(vector<string> & vec)
{
    QVector< QString > result;


    return result;

}

QVector<QVector <QString> > bogusMa(vector<vector<string> > & vec)
{

    QVector< QVector<QString> > result;


    return result;

}


#ifndef METHOD_H
#define METHOD_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <Method.h>

using namespace::std;

class Method{


public:
    static QVector<QString> bogus(vector<string> & vec);
    static QVector<QVector <QString> > bogusMa(vector<vector<string> > & vec);

};

#endif // METHOD_H
```

This is weird, because I don't get any error message when I am returning vectors containing anything else than QString. Sorry, if this sound like a dumb question, but I can't figure out exactly why I am getting this error. Does it have something to do with the include namespace statement in the header file? I don't see how those two might be connected. If it is the case, can you explain why it gives me an error?

Comment: Before we can help you, `this error != NULL` must be `TRUE`.

Comment: Just that there's no reference to what you mean by "this error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing a method, you need to specify the class there are in

```
QVector<QString> bogus(vector<string> & vec)
```

become

```
QVector<QString> Method::bogus(vector<string> & vec)
```

And

```
QVector<QVector <QString> > bogusMa(vector<vector<string> > & vec)
```

become

```
QVector<QVector <QString> > Method::bogusMa(vector<vector<string> > & vec)
```

The prototype for the method must also be included BEFORE its implementation, so you should move these after your class declaration.

Comment: what if they are not in the same file (I have a header and a cpp file)?

Comment: In that case you need to include the header in the cpp file, and in the main (the "Method::" are still necessary in the cpp)